# Return a view from a onchange function

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, openerp-8

I want to return a view from a onchange function ,but not able to redirect ..
Here is my code

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('product_id')
def product_id_change(self):
    model_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    if not self.product_id:
        return {'domain': {'product_uom': []}}

    vals = {}
    domain = {'product_uom': [('category_id', '=', self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id)]}
    if not self.product_uom or (self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id != self.product_uom.category_id.id):
    vals['product_uom'] = self.product_id.uom_id

    name = product.name_get()[0][1]
    if product.description_sale:
        name += '\n' + product.description_sale
    vals['name'] = name

    self._compute_tax_id()

    if self.order_id.pricelist_id and self.order_id.partner_id:
        vals['price_unit'] = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price(product.price, product.taxes_id, self.tax_id)
    self.update(vals)
    data_id = model_obj._get_id('hotelbeds', 'view_search_hotel')
    view_ids = model_obj.browse(data_id).res_id
    return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': _('Hotel Search'),
            'domain': domain,
            'view_id' :view_ids,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'hotel.search',
            'target': 'new'
            }
```

Kindly help with this issue ,where am i going wrong or something missing ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'Not able to redirect' (Please add more context to your question). Also i don't think you should be using `onchange` to return a view. What's the bigger problem you're trying to solve, There might be a better solution

Comment: Hello Danidee,Actualy I want to return the view when we select the product_id in order_line in quotation .So I inherited the onchange function and trying to return the view from that onchange but not able to return the view..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@api.onchange` decorated methods are not supposed to return anything. They just edit a "in memory" version of the object you're creating or editing. Odoo does not expect that method to return anything and will not take actions depending on the result of the method.

Best way to achieve what you're doing is to put a button next to the select field of the product. That button will call a method that will return the corresponding action.

```
<record id="your_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">your_view_name</field>
    <field name="model">your.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="product_id"/>
        <button name="redirect" string="Find hotel" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
    </field>
</record>
```

And in your model file

```
@api.multi
def redirect(self):
    model_obj = self.env['ir.model.data']
    if not self.product_id:
        return {'domain': {'product_uom': []}}
    vals = {}
    domain = {'product_uom': [('category_id', '=', self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id)]}
    if not self.product_uom or (self.product_id.uom_id.category_id.id != self.product_uom.category_id.id):
    vals['product_uom'] = self.product_id.uom_id
    name = product.name_get()[0][1]
    if product.description_sale:
        name += '\n' + product.description_sale
    vals['name'] = name
    self._compute_tax_id()
    if self.order_id.pricelist_id and self.order_id.partner_id:
        vals['price_unit'] = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price(product.price, product.taxes_id, self.tax_id)
    self.update(vals)
    data_id = model_obj._get_id('hotelbeds', 'view_search_hotel')
    view_ids = model_obj.browse(data_id).res_id
    return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': _('Hotel Search'),
            'domain': domain,
            'view_id' :view_ids,
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'hotel.search',
            'target': 'new'
            }
```

Comment: Hello @Majikat , Your solution is very good.and thats exactly what i have done . But the client needs the view to be opened without saving the record(he thinks that that saving record is time consuming ) and the button solution works when the record have saved .but he wants that there are 40 order lines which were saved and when he adds 41st order_line without saving the quotation when he clicks on button the action view should be returned .But it is not happening .So i had gone for onchange function ...but this solution also seems not working...can you give some suggestions !!

Comment: For that you should use an intermediate model. The model you use to do the selection, do not user `models.Model` when inheriting the class, use `models.TransientModel`. This kind of model is used for Wizards and is only saved in memory (and not in the database). But you can use its record like any other record.

Comment: ok ,so i make quotation entirly in wizard since the button i added is in xml only and i am returning a xml action for this and have not written any method ..here is my xml code for button                                                <button name="%(action_search_hotel)d" string="Search" type="action"
    icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-ltr" data-name="button" />

Comment: Clicking on a button in Odoo will save the record containing the button. Ok. If you want to completely trigger an action opening without having to click on a button, you'll have to do it on the frontend. Like modifying the form widget of Many2one so that selecting a product calls a function that opens an action. I think that can be performed.

Comment: Thank you @Majikat....I tried this method and it worked...only thing is it is working on all many2one fileds present so i have to find a way to so that it works fine only with one field...Thank you :)